# How can I bind with ninject when constructor requires an object?

Tags: c#, ninject

My unit of work object has 2 dependencies, a connection and a transaction. The transaction needs a connection in order for it to be bound. Unsure of how to handle this situation.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public IDbConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public IDbTransaction Transaction { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWork(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        this.Connection = connection;
        // In order to create the transaction, it needs the passed in IDbConnection.
    }

    public void Commit()
    {

    }

    public void Rollback()
    {

    }
}
```

How would I handle this situation?

```
Bind<IDbTransaction>().To<SqlTransaction>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind it like this. In way that IDbTransaction will be tied to IDbConnection.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IDbConnection>()
      .To<SqlConnection>()
      .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);
kernel.Bind<IDbTransaction>()
      .ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<IDbConnection>().BeginTransaction());
```

But I don't see any reason why should you do this like that. You can simply use `Connection.BeginTransaction()` inside your `UnitOfWork` and remove that dependency on `IDbTransaction` from constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the binding. I can't `Commit()` or `RollBack()` without a transaction? Or at least I don't think so.

Comment: You can't Commit or Rollback without an transaction. But you can let your `IDBConnection` to create `IDbTransaction` via the `BeginTransaction()` method. Thus you do not need to pass the `IDbTransaction` to constructor if `IDbConnection` is already there - let's say, they should be tied together. However the binding I wrote has actually the same effect.

Comment: Oh gosh, sorry about that. I didn't realize `BeginTransaction` returns `IDbTransaction`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to follow the following sample that should make it work.

```
private void RegisterDependencyResolver()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();         
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            kernel.Bind(typeof(DataContext)).ToMethod(context => new DataContext(connectionString));
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));            
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }
```

Here is another related discussion, as an additional resource to look - [**Ninject, Repository and DAL**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10008923/1437962)